# iOS Charts | Getting orange/brown colour axis lines in Line chart view randomly

Tags: ios, swift, charts, uicollectionview

I am using LineChartView in collection view cells, but randomly when I scroll sometimes orange/brown axis lines are being displayed.

[image]

Code I used to create LineChartView

```
    let view = LineChartView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    view.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    view.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    view.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    view.xAxis.enabled = false
    view.xAxis.axisLineColor = .clear
    view.rightAxis.enabled = false
    view.rightAxis.axisLineColor = .clear
    view.leftAxis.enabled = false
    view.leftAxis.axisLineColor = .clear
    view.drawBordersEnabled = false
    view.legend.enabled = false
     
    let values = (0..<32).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
       let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(10) + 3)
       return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val)
    }
    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: values)
    set1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    set1.drawValuesEnabled = false
    set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
    set1.setColor(UIColor.black)

    view.data = LineChartData(dataSets: [set1])
```

Using danielgindi / Charts (3.6.0)

Comment: Add this property : view.highlightPerTapEnabled = false

Comment: Thanks @RajaKishan Worked like a charm, didn't realised that it was due to tapping or dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supplement to @ Raja Kishan's suggestion

```
    // for tapping
    view.highlightPerTapEnabled = false
    // for dragging
    view.highlightPerDragEnabled = false
```